# Give the domain and range of $y=\log(x-3)+2$

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am so confused. I think the domain is $x>3$ but is the range ARN or is it $y>0$ . . .

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the logarithmic expression $y = \log(f(x))$ exists when $f(x) > 0$, which implies that $x - 3 > 0$.  So the domain of $y = \log(x - 3) + 2$ is $x > 3$.  Since the range of the logarithmic function with any linear equation is $\mathbb{R}$, the range of the given function is $\mathbb{R}$ as well.

Comment: I thought a log was always positive? so if x=5 wouldn't y=log(5-3)+2  y=log 4 so wouldn't y always come out positive?

Comment: Please Help! this is confusing. @NasuSama

Comment: No, logarithm of a number between $0$ and $1$ is negative.

Comment: What? I am so confused. Maybe I need to go back and learn more about logarithms. @RobertIsrael

Comment: @sammy The range of $y = \log(f(x))$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$.  Hope you know this.